# Localization in struts1

Tags: java, localization, internationalization, struts, struts-1

I have a requirement in my project to support Localization in web application.

The project is a web application which provides services to its users.

It is based on Struts 1.2.

Requirement: The labels in the jsp page can be controlled according to the user's preference i.e. the labels can differ according to the user logged in.

The user can change the text of the label what he/she wants to see.

How can I achieve this in Struts 1.2?

I know about Struts i18n, but it is based on the locale.

What I'm thinking is to create a separate property file for each user. How can I use the same property file for displaying the labels in JSP in Struts 1.2?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

In a single property file, you can have multiple resource ids with different username.

> For ex:
>   user1.title=Title for user1
>
> user2.title=title for user2

and create dynamic key in bean:message depends upon the user loggedin.

In struts-config.xml

```
<message-resources parameter="com.struts.MessageResource" key="appResource"></message-resources>
```

In JSP:

```
<%  
String username= (String) request.getAttribute("username");  
%>
<bean:message bundle="appResource" key="<%= username + ".title"%>" />
```

Instead of having different labels with respect to user for their preferences, you can control user's preferences by creating your own templates and make use of them. This way, you don't need to add resource ids for every new user.

Comment: thanks @Karthik for your response.

I think it would be better to use different property file so that it can be easier to maintain. Additionally, we can also provide a front end screen to the user to save the preferences.

1 more thing.. Can the location of this MessageResource property file be other than the war or jar?

Comment: Addition: these MessageResource property files can be stored in a separate location

Comment: You can write custom struts-tag to read your resource ids from different location using resource bundles.